# Issues while automate the Freecharge("https://www.freecharge.in")

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate Freecharge("https://www.freecharge.in")Website in Selenium using Java.After login into the website I executed following steps:

Step1: Click on Mobile

Step2: Enter Mobile Number

Step3: Click on Postpaid Radio button

Step4: Same for Operator

Step5: Click Directly on Proceed.

Step6: Enter value in amount Textbox. It is not considering the amount and showing Zero.**(Need help in entering the amount)**

I wrote the following code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.freecharge.in/");
    //WAIT
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='_3mvx0']")));
    //CLICK ON LOGIN
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='_3mvx0']")).click();
    //ENTER DETAILS
    driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("email_id");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
    //WAIT
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    //LOGIN
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn _32_N-']")).click();
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Mobile")));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mobile")).click();
    //ENTER NUMBER TO BE RECHARGE
    driver.findElement(By.name("number")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("number")).sendKeys("9811105989" );
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")));
    //SELECT PLAN AND OPERATOR 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1LZRh']/label[2]/span[2]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='operator']")));
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Vodafone Postpaid");
    //WAIT
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    //PROCEED
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    //ENTER AMOUNT
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='amount']")).sendKeys("400");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn _24xNn']")).click();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for postpaid radio button

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1LZRh']/label[2]/span[2]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

click the radio button with:

```
JavascriptExecuter js = (JavascriptExecuter)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", <your radio button web element>);
```

you can locate the button by using xpath:
(//*[@type ='radio'])[last()]